# How to parse key-value based data from a text-format by a provided list of property names and write it back as json-format?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, text, match

I'm trying to write a JSON file that contains a matched words from a text like this

```
servicepoint ‏ 200135644 watchid ‏ 7038842
```

so each servicepoint and watchid will be inserted to the Object table only one time using this code:

```
function readfile() {
  Tesseract.recognize('form.png', 'ara', {

    logger: m => console.log(m)

  }).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
    console.log(text); /* this line here */
    var obj = {
      table: []
    };
    const info = ['servicepoint', 'watchid'];
    for (k = 0; k < info.length; k++) {
      var result = text.match(new RegExp(info[k] + '\\s+(\\w+)'))[1];
      obj.table.push({
        servicepoint: /* Here i want to insert the number after servicepoint*/ ,
        watchid: /*also i want to insert the number after watchid to the Object table*/
      });
    }
    var json = JSON.stringify(obj); /* converting the object table to json file*/
    var fs = require('fs'); /* and then write json file contians the data*/
    fs.writeFile('myjsonfile.json', json, 'utf8', callback);
  })
};
```

Comment: does the space is the separator ? and the format of your text like this format key space value

Comment: The line of text actually reads (fortunately the OP just copied/pasted this line from the environment) ... `'servicepoint U+200F 200135644 watchid U+200F 7038842'`). The OP has to take a sanitizing task into account before processing the text based data; or the regex handling needs to be aware of special unicode characters.

Comment: @PeterSeliger thanks for your comment and yes I'm facing a problem with the Unicode characters i can't detect the number after each word how can i fix the regex

Comment: I would use a conservative pattern which tries to match the keyword from the list like e.g. `'servicepoint'` followed by everything which is not internationally recognized as either letter or number ... `[^\p{L}\p{N}]+` followed by a capturing group which matches everything that is not an internationally recognized whitespace `([^\p{Z}]+)` ... Thus the dynamically build pattern for the latter array item example would be ... [`/servicepoint[^\p{L}\p{N}]+([^\p{Z}]+)/gu`](https://regex101.com/r/StNzHq/1) or just `/servicepoint[^\p{L}\p{N}]+([^\p{Z}]+)/u` without **g**lobal flag.

Comment: One could even drop the **u**nicode flag and translate the above pattern back into [`/servicepoint\W+(\w+)/`](https://regex101.com/r/StNzHq/3) which is pretty close to the OP's original code. The OP just needs to trade the `\\s+` for an `\\W+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From one of my above comments ...

> One could even drop the **u**nicode flag and translate the above pattern back into [`/servicepoint\W+(\w+)/`](https://regex101.com/r/StNzHq/3) which is pretty close to the OP's original code. The OP just needs to trade the `\\s+` for an `\\W+`

In addition to the proposed pattern change I also would change the OP's *thenables* into more clear tasks like separating **file-reading** from **just data parsing/extraction** from **json-conversion/writing**.

I also want to state that the OP's desired `data.table` based format can not be an array but has to be a pure key-value structure (object) since one can just either aggregate a single object (one entry at time while iterating the property names) or push single property only items (one item at time while iterating the property names) into an array. (The OP tries to create a multi-entry object though also pushing it.)

The next provided code shows the approach. The implementation follows the OP's original code. It just uses async-await syntax and mocks/fakes the file reading and writing processes.

```js
async function readFile(fileName) {
  console.log({ fileName });

  // return await Tesseract.recognize(fileName, 'ara', {
  // 
  //   logger: m => console.log(m)
  // });

  // fake it ...
  return (await new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(
      resolve,
      1500,
      { data: { text: 'servicepoint ‏ 200135644 watchid ‏ 7038842'} }
    )
  ));
}
/*async */function parseDataFromTextAndPropertyNames(text, propertyNames) {
  console.log({ text, propertyNames });

  return propertyNames
    .reduce((table, key) =>
      Object.assign(table, {

        [ key ]: RegExp(`${ key }\\W+(\\w+)`)
          .exec(text)?.[1] ?? ''

      }), {});
}
async function writeParsedTextDataAsJSON(fileName, table) {
  console.log({ table });

  // const fs = require('fs');
  // fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify({ table }), 'utf8', callback);

  // fake it ...
  return (await new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => {

      console.log({ fileName, json: JSON.stringify({ table }) });
      resolve({ success: true });

    }, 1500)
  ));
}

console.log('... running ...');

(async () => {
  const { data: { text } } = await readFile('form.png');

  const data = /*await*/
    parseDataFromTextAndPropertyNames(text, ['servicepoint', 'watchid']);

  const result = await writeParsedTextDataAsJSON('myjsonfile.json', data);

  console.log({ result });
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `String.match` to get the required variable values for your two keys: "servicepoint" and "watchid".

I would suggest using [this match pattern](https://regexr.com/6nh22) to get your two data points.

Then you'll need to create and then stringify the JSON, giving you something like: `{servicepoint: 1323, watchid: 234}`

I assume you have many of these rows, so you'll want to add each JSON key-value to an array. You can then `JSON.stringify(dataArray)` to generate the valid JSON text to write to a file.